# how to upload photos on facebook apps using form multipart/form-data

Tags: upload, facebook, photo, multipartform-data

Recently I am working with a facebook application but anyhow facebook is not supporting form post with $_FILES, So that I can not upload any file with php regular file upload system.
Now I am trying to use file uploading with file url location to upload it in a new created photo album.

Is there any easy suggestion so user can upload photos from his/her computer using my application?

Thanks in advance!
phpfarmer

Answer (score 0):

finally my code works, facebook didn't obey the rfc standard, that lead to confusing

```
final String BOUNDERY = "3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f";
final String CRLF = "\r\n";
StringBuilder sbBody_1 = new StringBuilder();
sbBody_1.append("--" + BOUNDERY + CRLF);
sbBody_1.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"source\"" + CRLF);
sbBody_1.append(CRLF);
StringBuilder sbBody_2 = new StringBuilder();
sbBody_2.append(CRLF + "--" + BOUNDERY + "--");
URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=" + accessToken);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + BOUNDERY);
connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write(sbBody_1.toString().getBytes());
out.write(bFile);
out.write(sbBody_2.toString().getBytes());
out.close();
BufferedReader bips = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String temp = null;
while ((temp = bips.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.d("fbnb", temp);
}
bips.close();
connection.disconnect();
```

by the way, **bFile is the byte array of the bitmap**